# Using a POST Request To Get a JSON Object From a Different Domain

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I've been trying to figure out how to send a POST request via ajax to another domain's page. It seems like everywhere I went, I was told that you cannot simply use a POST request when it is cross domain.

I am trying to get Soil Information from the USGS site via a POST request. Here is the page explaining the process: http://earthquake.usgs.gov/hazards/apps/vs30/documentation.php
Here is my jQuery:

```
var postObj = {
    json: 'true',
    site_name: 'model',
    top_left_lat: 0,
    top_left_lon: 0,
    bottom_right_lat: 1,
    bottom_right_lon: 1,
    slope_type: 'stable',
    output_types: ['jpg', 'xyz', 'grd']
}

$.ajax({
    url: "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/hazards/apps/vs30/vs30.php",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: postObj,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Here is my console after execution:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/hazards/apps/vs30/vs30.php?callback=jQuery111007…es%5B%5D=jpg&output_types%5B%5D=xyz&output_types%5B%5D=grd&_=1402961661663 ". jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < vs30.php:1
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Did the USGS site forget 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'? Please help!

Comment: what is the actual response? it appears that is returning a page. also, jsonp defeats cors.

Comment: @DanielA.White This is the full URL: http://earthquake.usgs.gov/hazards/apps/vs30/vs30.php?callback=jQuery111002639128111768514_1402963335564&json=true&site_name=Model+a&top_left_lat=33.996&top_left_lon=-118.162&bottom_right_lat=34.097&bottom_right_lon=-118.061&slope_type=stable&output_types%5B%5D=jpg&output_types%5B%5D=xyz&output_types%5B%5D=grd&_=1402963335565... which takes me to a page with the three items I want but they are blank files, trying to download them leads to an error. Actual response within chrome's console is just that page's source code.

Answer (score 1):

JSONP does not support POST requests, so your request is converted to a GET requests with the information from postObj appended to the query string. That's why the API responds with an error message (obviously formatted as HTML).

Additionally, the [Documentation](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/hazards/apps/vs30/documentation.php) does not contain any information about JSONP. I think that they only support normal JSON, not JSONP.

This JSON may not be accessed using a modern browser because of the Same Origin Policy. As you wrote in your question, this is not your fault - the USGS simply does not send CORS headers. If you try to send your POST request with a tool that does not implement the SOP, it works. For example, the following request with wget is successful:

```
wget --post-data "json=true&site_name=model&top_left_lat=0&top_left_lon=0&bottom_right_lat=0.1&bottom_right_lon=0.1&slope_type=stable&output_types%5B%5D=jpg&output_types%5B%5D=xyz&output_types%5B%5D=grd" http://earthquake.usgs.gov/hazards/apps/vs30/vs30.php
```

Either they "forgot" the CORS headers (as you wrote), or this API is not designed for requests from web browsers, only for server-side applications etc.

One solution could be to have a proxy on your own server which forwards the request to the USGS server. If your server supports mod_proxy, use [the ProxyPass directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) in the .htaccess file of a directory:

```
ProxyPass / http://earthquake.usgs.gov/hazards/apps/vs30/vs30.php
```

and send your jQuery AJAX request to this directory.

If you cannot use .htaccess, your server doesn't support mod_proxy etc. you can use a simple PHP script with [HttpRequest](http://php.net/httprequest.send) to write your own "proxy":

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$req = new HttpRequest('http://earthquake.usgs.gov/hazards/apps/vs30/vs30.php', HttpRequest::METH_POST);
$req->addPostFields($_POST);
echo $req->send()->getBody();
```

(please note that you should implement some checks for the fields, catch exceptions etc., this is just a basic example to show how it could work)

Comment: Changing 'jsonp' to 'json' returns the XMLHTTPREQUEST error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://earthquake.usgs.gov/hazards/apps/vs30/vs30.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8008' is therefore not allowed access.